# How do I get my app to run/debug on a Galaxy Tab?

Tags: android, remote-debugging

According to the documentation this should "just work" but it certainly isn't for me.

I'm developing an app using Eclispe on a mac running 10.6.

I've switched the "USB Debugging" option on on the Galaxy. I've left the USB mode set to "Kies" as switching it to Mass Storage did not seem to help.

When I do an "adb devices" command the Galaxy shows up as it should.

So how do I get Eclipse to run my app on the Galaxy rather than in the emulator. Every time I press Run it just runs the Emulator - the documentation suggests I should be given some choice as to what to run it on at that point. I cannot see any options to add the real hardware in the AVD manager. Am I missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the project `Properties`, select `Run/Debug Settings`, select your Launch configuration, hit `Edit`, on the tab `Target` set it to `Manual`, `OK`, `OK`.

Comment: oh yar welcome! I was hitting my head against a wall for a while before figured it out myself:)